# How to show checkboxes as checked when values are set in the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, checkbox, foreach

I use foreach to show data came from database.

This is for Plan_data

```
<?php foreach ($veddingPlanData as $row) { ?>

<input box with value containing "echo row->value_name" >

<?php  }  ?>
```

This is for task data as check box [here I want to show the checkbox list in which the task is given to plan_id they appear as cheeked checkbox and remaining list with not checked status)

```
<?php foreach ($veddingPlanTaskMappingData as $row) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="task_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->task_id ;?>" checked><?php echo $row->task_name?><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Here I show the whole task list in check box.

```
<?php foreach ($allVedingTasks as $row) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="task_id" value="<?php echo $row->task_id ;?>" ><?php echo $row->task_name?><br>
<?php } ?>
```

I want to foreach the task_name list with selected some task as there mapped plan_id.

Comment: You are working on this project from 14 july.i checked your last 4 question all are from this project.

Comment: yes sir...  my salary depends on this project..   :)  @Bugfixer

Comment: @ankitsuthar why you are not given your feedback in answers???Weather is answer is working or not???

Comment: @ankitsuthar Sounds like you've been being a **help vampire**:http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found It

```
 <?php
              $arrSelVedTask = array();
               foreach ($veddingPlanTaskMappingData as $row) { 
              $arrSelVedTask[$row->task_id] = '';
               }
            ?>


                                              <div class="form-group">

                                                  <lable for="task_id" class="control-label col-sm-12">Plan Task LIST:</lable>
                                                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                  <div class="checkbox" style="margin-left:40px;">

                                                  <?php foreach ($allVedingTasks as $row) { 

                  if(isset($arrSelVedTask[$row->task_id])) {
                      ?><input type="checkbox" name="task_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->task_id ;?>" checked ><?php echo $row->task_name; ?><br><?php
                  }
                  else{
                      ?><input type="checkbox" name="task_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->task_id ;?>" ><?php echo $row->task_name; ?><br><?php
                  }
               }  
                  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a check:

```
<?php
foreach ($veddingPlanTaskMappingData as $row) {
  $checked = ($row->task_id == YOUR_CONDITION) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="task_id[]" value="<?php echo $row->task_id ;?>" <?php echo $checked?>><?php echo $row->task_name?><br>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [set_checkbox](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html) Of CI

```
<input type="checkbox" name="task_id" value="<?php echo $row->task_id ;?>" <?php echo set_checkbox('task_id', $row->task_id); ?> ><?php echo $row->task_name?>
```

Comment: sorry sir..   i tried this but i got all checkbox  selected. @Saty

Answer (score 0):

at first in your model fetch the value of checkbox which is in your database then call that function in controller and pass the value to view page. then use if statement with every checkbox item to check whether the value is same or not. and write `echo "checked";`command if the condition match.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we will take all the categories than we are taking an Id and using it for showing the checked list from the database. First we select the table values based on Id than we will fetch the record. We are having the data in the database column using , comma like 1,2,3,5,9. Than we save it in array and at last we just show that array to the page.

```
$table="select * from categorytable";
$this->result=mysqli_query($this->con,$table);
$this->count=mysqli_num_rows($this->result);
if($this->count < 1)
{
    return "<div class='form-group'>".$messages->getResponseMessage("No category is added.", "Warning")."</div>";
}
else
{
    $alert='';
$select="select Category from table where Id='$id'";
    $result=  mysqli_query($this->con, $select);
    $amrow=  mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $getAminity=$amrow["Category"];
    $getArray=  explode(",",$getAminity);
    while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($this->result))
    {
        if(in_array($row[Id],$getArray)){
            $alert.="<div class=col-md-2><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type=checkbox id='catval[]' checked name='catval[]' value='$row[Id]'/> $row[Name]</label></div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $alert.="<div class=col-md-2><label class='checkbox-inline'><input type=checkbox id='catval[]' name='catval[]' value='$row[Id]'/> $row[Name]</label></div>";
        }

    }
```